# BufferedReader inconsistently hanging on my socket's inputstream

Tags: java, http, inputstream, bufferedreader

I am writing a Java HTTP server.  I thought the entire server was working and it is using threading.  However, I'm realizing that the piece of code that reads the request into a BufferedReader is not working consistently.

Here is the code that reads an incoming request:

```
private String receive(WebSocket webSocket) throws IOException {
  int chr;
  System.out.println("Receiving!");
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

  while ( (chr = webSocket.in().read() ) != -1) {
    buffer.append((char) chr);
    if ( !webSocket.in().ready())
      break;
  }
  return buffer.toString();
}
```

My Websocket class just wraps the Socket and provides an in and an out.  I did this so that I could mock out the socket and test my server.

The Websocket class looks like this:

```
package http.server.socket;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SystemSocket implements WebSocket {
  private Socket theConnection;
  private BufferedReader in;
  private OutputStream out;

  public SystemSocket(Socket theConnection) throws IOException {
    this.theConnection = theConnection;
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(theConnection.getInputStream()));
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(theConnection.getOutputStream());
  }

  public BufferedReader in() throws IOException {
    return in;
  }

  public OutputStream out() throws IOException {
    return out;
  }

  public void close() throws IOException {
    in.close();
    out.close();
    theConnection.close();
  }
}
```

The problem is that with each url the user enters in a browser, two requests are made - one for the page requested and one for the favicon.  Sometimes - it seems - the favicon request is not coming in and the thread hangs.

Here's some debugging information I have printing to the console **when things go right**:

```
Receiving!
Receiving!
REQUEST STRING = GET /color_picker.html HT
[20130821 20:29:23] REQUEST: http://localhost:5000/color_picker.html
[20130821 20:29:23] PAGE RENDERED
REQUEST STRING = GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
[20130821 20:29:23] REQUEST: http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico
[20130821 20:29:23] PAGE RENDERED
```

The "Receiving" message is getting printed whenever the request is getting read.  So, in this case, the "Receiving" message got printed twice, two requests came in and two things were rendered.  But then, the same page (but at a different time) will do this **(after about 10 seconds)**:

```
Receiving!
Receiving!
REQUEST STRING = GET /color_picker.html HTTP/1.1
[20130821 20:41:25] REQUEST: http://localhost:5000/color_picker.html
[20130821 20:41:25] PAGE RENDERED
REQUEST STRING = 
Exception in thread "ServerThread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
  at http.request.Parser.setRequestLineData(Parser.java:42)
  at http.request.Parser.setRequestHash(Parser.java:27)
  at http.request.Parser.parse(Parser.java:13)
  at http.request.Request.get(Request.java:18)
  at http.server.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:39)
```

All the subsequent errors are because the request string is null.  But I can't figure out why the Request string is null.  I can't even figure out how to debug.

Can anyone help??

Also important to note that if the second request string doesn't come in right away, the user can request a new url and it will cause the second hung process to complete (so then the fourth request url will be what hangs).  So, it's only when the user stops requesting things, on the last request after about 10 seconds, I will get the error.  Sometimes I can request 20 different pages and it's only after I stop requesting pages and wait a few seconds, that I will see an error.  I think this is what is happening??

**UPDATE:**

Per the request, here is the setRequestLineData() method:

```
private void setRequestLineData() {
  requestHash = new HashMap<String, String>();

  if (requestLineParts.length == 3) {
    requestHash.put("httpMethod", requestLineParts[0]);
    requestHash.put("url", requestLineParts[1]);  //line 42
    requestHash.put("httpProtocol", requestLineParts[2]);
  }
  else {
    requestHash.put("httpMethod", requestLineParts[0]);
    requestHash.put("url", requestLineParts[1]);
    requestHash.put("queryString", requestLineParts[2]);
    requestHash.put("httpProtocol", requestLineParts[3]);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I think I figured out more about what is going on here with my mentor's help.  His thought is that once a request is received, the browser starts another request right away to reduce load time for the next request.  This sound plausible to me since I can load page after page after page, but it's only about 10 seconds after the last page is requested that I get an error.  Currently, I'm handling this with a custom exception, but am working on a better solution.  Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: Is `http.request.Parser` your class? Please show us the `setRequestLineData()` method.

Comment: Care to mention why the downvote?  I could still help if you let me know.

Comment: I didn't downvote you @MarioRossi.  Sorry.

Comment: @GregKopff, I added it.  It is simply trying to parse the request and when the request is null, it throws an error.

Answer (score 3):

`ready()` isn't a valid test for end of message. It only tells you whether there is data available to be read without blocking. TCP isn't a message-oriented protocol, it is a byte-stream protocol. If you want messages you must implement them yourself, e.g. as lines, length-value tuples, type-length-value tuples, serialized objects, XML documents, ...

There are few if any correct uses of `ready()` (or `available()`), and this isn't one of them.

Comment: Thank you, EJP.  Per the Java Docs, "The ready method of the underlying stream returns false, indicating that further input requests would block."  It seems the stream is empty and is blocking.  So I was using that command to break if it was indeed blocking.  I also tried surrounding the while loop in another while loop checking for ready() but it didn't work.  Do you have another suggestion?  Am I on the right track?

Comment: The point is that blocking has nothing to do with message completion. You have to keep reading until you have a complete message, and ready() cannot help you with that. If getting a compete message involves blocking, so be it.